# error 0x8007045d the request could not be performed because of an I/O device error

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I am trying to copy files from D: partition to USB drive, but I get message

```
error 0x8007045d the request could not be performed because of an I/O device error
```

I google it, and I found a couple of method but doesn't work for me. 
I tried to run into `Safe Mode` but again same error.
Second thing I download TeraCopy and after couple of hours of copy 2GB of data I also get same problem. 
Third thing that I tried to move to Selective Mode into `msconfig` but also same problem
And last thing which I try to copy data from Partition C: to D: it works perfectly, but from D: to C: doesn't work
Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: right click on d drive >Properties > Tools Tab > Error Check and Optimize your drive.

Comment: I did it, but doesnt solve problem.

Comment: you might need to repair your installation of windows

Comment: You mean just to boot WIndows and user Repair Tool or ...?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: https://www.earthslab.com/computer-science/error-0x8007045d-device-i-o-error/
Did you try these options

Comment: Not yet. FIrst I need to check my HDD using HD Tune as @DavidPostill sad